Program to add users in 2 different groups to one group in bash
Working on an assignment for class and I can not figure out the logic to make it work. I need to create an automated script that adds users from 2 different groups into one group. I've managed to loop through the users, but I can't figure out how to connect user and their existing group to add them into the new group. This is what I've worked out so far, mostly by browsing other related questions. The assignment requires me to use at least one variable, a repetition structure and a compound conditional statement. Thanks!
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(getent passwd);
do
if id -nG "$user" | grep "groups"; then
echo "$user in groups"
else
echo "$user not in group"
fi
done


Even the first line if wrong. Check the output of: getent passwd it's column separated, by :, so you need to cut

what does ... users from 2 different groups ... mean? look for users who are members in each of a specific pair of groups? look for users who have membership in exactly 2 groups (regardless of the group names)? look for any users who are members in at least 1 of 2 specific groups? something else? if perusing specific groups, where are you storing those group names?

If I understand correctly you want to add all the users from group1 and group2 to group3, then you can do something like this
#! /bin/bash

uig() {
  awk -F: '{print $4}' < <(getent group "$1")
}

g1='group1'
g2='group2'
g3='group3'

printf '%s,%s\n' "$(uig "$g1")" "$(uig "$g2")" | xargs -d, -L1 sudo usermod –a –G "$g3"

The function gets the users from the specified group and then concatenating the results from the 2 groups invokes usermod for each user.
